# Assembly Load Error - > Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, hierarchyid

In my .NET CORE project, I'm using layered structure and for Spatial Types I am using

`dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Version="1.1.0"`

Here are my **.csproj files**:

**Entities.csproj :**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**DataAccess.csproj :**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npoi.Mapper" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**WebUI.csproj :**  --> ASP.NET CORE

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
      
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>      
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />      
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.2" />      
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.2" />      
    <PackageReference Include="Scrutor" Version="3.2.1" />      
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have tried below:

- Install Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package from **Nuget**
- Create a **web.config** file and add :

```
<runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

- Before dotMorten's Nuget package, I was using `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` package,
  but at that time period, I was having a "Constructor" exception for HierarchyId while I was creating a migration, so I've decided to use **dotMorten's** package.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE FOR READERS**

Since I couldn't solve this problem,

I am back to using `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` since migration support has been fixed in v1.1 and is now available in Nuget.

`EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` running without errors in .NET Core

***For Your Information:** I will not accept this as the correct answer, because this answer is not providing any information about the main issue!*